# How do you get a stack trace of a running process?

Tags: mac, macos

On Linux, you can examine `/proc/$PID/stack`. Is there an equivalent on OSX?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/24523118/32453

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

1. Open Activity Monitor.
2. Select the target process.
3. Click on the gear icon in top left.
4. Select "Sample Process" from appeared menu.

[image]

It will display detailed info about process:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's always a good idea to add some text describing the images.  The text can be picked-up by Search for when others have a similar question.  See [answer] for tips on providing good answers.

Comment: WOW!! I didn't know about that! I was trying to get something like this with lldb without success... Thanks!! +1!

Comment: See also the sample command https://stackoverflow.com/q/24523118/32453